# Custom sound not working with Awesome Notifications on iOS

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use a custom sound for notifications in my Flutter app using the Awesome Notifications plugin. However, the custom sound is not playing when the notification is displayed. I've tried using resource to specify the sound file, but is not working.

Here's the code I'm using to initialize the Awesome Notifications plugin and define the notification channel with the custom sound:

```
  AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    'resource://drawable/res_app_icon',
    [
      // Notification channel definition
      NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'basic_channel',
          channelName: 'Basic Notifications',
          defaultColor: Colors.blue,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          channelDescription: 'Description for basic notifications',
          playSound: true,
          soundSource: 'assets/sounds/water_droplet.aiff'),
    ],
  );
// send local notification
  await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
      customSound: 'assets/sounds/water_droplet.aiff',
      id: Random().nextInt(100),
      channelKey: 'basic_channel',
      title: 'test',
      body: 'test',
      payload: {'schedule': 'immediate'},
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NotificationChannel(
    channelKey: 'sound_channel',
    channelName: 'Basic Notifications',
    defaultColor: Colors.blue,
    importance: NotificationImportance.High,
    channelDescription: 'Description for basic notifications',
    channelShowBadge: false,
    playSound: true,
    soundSource: 'resource://raw/water_droplet',
  )
```